# Непонятный вывод numpy массива

Tags: python, numpy

После использования алгоритма логистической регрессии при помощи Tensorflow и вывожу его через print я получаю такой список numpy:

```
[1.21943909e-04 4.43954542e-05 8.72819116e-05 3.13282258e-04
 1.06825649e-04 7.38583900e-05 8.19325633e-05 4.19554410e-05
 2.60391378e-04 8.89145846e-05]
```

Если я хочу что-то с ним сделать, к примеру вывести через цикл, я получаю такие значения на выходе (так же при любых операциях с этим массивом):

```
0.00012194390897261181
4.439545420470247e-05
8.728191156661681e-05
0.0003132822577153944
0.00010682564880684135
7.385839002667984e-05
8.19325633026861e-05
4.195544099963649e-05
0.00026039137776540615
8.891458460943436e-05
```

Класс элементов в массиве - numpy.float64.
С чем связано это поведение и как сделать так, чтобы вывод был корректным.

Comment: Вывод абсолютно корректный. Ну нет квадратных скобочек - напечатайте.

Comment: Дайте определение "корректного вывода". Чем вас не устраивает [Экспоненциальная запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)?

Comment: Я не очень умен в математике и около математической теме и меня смутило, что когда я вывожу список у меня в нем находится число 1.219439089, а при вычислениях это число представляется как 0.0001219439089. С экспоненциальной записью не знаком

Comment: Там где видите букву e просто читайте "на 10 в степени". И все сойдется